# Нужен пример использования SQL-скрипта в Django

Tags: python, sqlite3, sqlite, django, sql

Ситуация: изменили схему модели (добавили одно поле, удалили другое). Нужно написать SQL-скрипт (я так понимаю, с ALTER'ми), чтобы при его вызове вносились изменения в базу `sqlite3`. Как писать? В каком формате? Как вызывать? Если он будет в папке `/sql/`, то вызывать по полному пути или в настройках можно определить как-то? В общем, нужен живой пример действий от А до Я на простейшей ситуации.

П.С. django evolution, south и т.д. не предлагать. Хочу разобраться, как это делаеться "ручками".

UPD. Писать вручную в консоле - не то, что я хочу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**: из консоли

```
./manage.py dbshell
```

отрывается sql консоль.
Пишите запрос, типа:

```
ALTER TABLE profile_profile ADD COLUMN "age" integer;
```

Вот тут структура запросов в sqlite типа ALTER TABLE http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html там же есть ссылки на описание каждой из элементов структуры, углубляясь все глубже поймете суть.

**2**: Если же хотите скрипт в питоне, положите его допустим в корень проекта около settings.py и назовите sql.py.
Внутри

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(project.settings)
from django.db import connection

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('ALTER TABLE profile_profile ADD COLUMN "age" integer;')
```

запускать:

```
python sql.py
```

Comment: в точку! спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если поменяли модель - то открываете консоль и пишете все alter table вручную. Зачем скрипт?

Comment: нужен скрипт, хочу разобраться как работает.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите в текстовом файле любые sql-команды (как в первом ответе), сохраните например в директории sql проекта, как в ответе выше, а потом зайдите в папку проекта и вызовите:

```
./manage.py dbshell < sql/script.sql
```

или

```
mysql -uroot -proot my_project_db_name < /absolute-path-to-project/sql/script.sql
```

или то же с относительным путем, скажем если вы в папке проекта

```
mysql -uroot -proot my_project_db_name < sql/script.sql
```

Comment: а если не mysql?

Comment: Тогда наверное подойдет первый вариант с `./manage.py dbshell` или какие-то подвохи с другими субд?